# Can I use google-cloud-trace times in google-cloud-monitoring?

Tags: google-cloud-monitoring, google-cloud-trace

I'm using google cloud tracing. It's recording the time my API's take to execute - which is working well.

Is it possible to setup explicit monitoring on that using google cloud monitoring? IE, setup a notification if I go over a threshold?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any way to add metrics from traces in Google Cloud Monitoring.
However, depending on the library you use to record trace some provide "trace metrics".

In my case, I use OpenTelemetry to create traces and send them to an OpenTelemetry collector before pushing them to GCP. The collector can be configured to use the [`spanmetrics` connector](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/blob/main/connector/spanmetricsconnector/README.md) which will generate count and latency metrics from your traces. These new metrics can then be used in Google Cloud Monitoring (with alerting if necessary).

Answer (score -1):

You can [create a custom metric](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics) and use it to [create a alerting policies](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/).

After you got the custom metric created. The policy can be created with the following parameters:

- resource type: Custom metric.
- If Metric: the metric you created.
- Condition: above.
- Threshold: whatever you estimate will need to trigger the alert.